# Can not load a product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ce-1.9.0.1, product-collection

In magento 1.9

I want to overwrite the function `prepareProductCollection($collection)` of the `catalog/layer` model.

Because, I only want to display simple products, so I want to do:

```
public function prepareProductCollection($collection){

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')
        ->getProductAttributes())
        ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addUrlRewrite();

    if(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
    {
        $collection->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')
        ->getQuery()->getQueryText());
    }

    $ids = VF_Singleton::getInstance()->getProductIds();
    if($ids)
    {
        $collection->addIdFilter($ids);
    }

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);

    return $this;
}
```

But when I do that, I have this error:

> SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

See the full error (including trace) here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XO5Z.png

Comment: Can you post the result of `Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText()` this

Comment: Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText() result screen
http://i.stack.imgur.com/WyHrL.png